# Changing the opacity of the polygons in the Python Bezier package

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bezier

I want to change the opacity the polygon plots made with
this [Python Bezier package](https://bezier.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Here is the code I tried:

```py
import bezier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

plt.clf()

nodes0 = numpy.asfortranarray([[0.0, 1.0, 2.0], [0.0, -1.0, 0.0]])
edge0 = bezier.Curve(nodes0, degree=2)

nodes1 = numpy.asfortranarray([[2.0, 2.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
edge1 = bezier.Curve(nodes1, degree=1)

nodes2 = numpy.asfortranarray([[2.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 2.0, 1.0]])
edge2 = bezier.Curve(nodes2, degree=2)

nodes3 = numpy.asfortranarray([[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0]])
edge3 = bezier.Curve(nodes3, degree=1)

curved_poly = bezier.CurvedPolygon(edge0, edge1, edge2, edge3)

# ax.set_alpha(1.0)                    # <-- I tried this, does not produce any effect.
ax = curved_poly.plot(pts_per_edge=12) # <-- Does not take alpha argument.

# plt.plot(alpha=1)                    # <-- I tried this, does not produce any effect.
plt.show()
```

The code produces the following plots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Remember that if you're using an open source package, and the documentation is insufficient to perform some elementary action, it's wise to file an issue on the project issue tracker to make sure that the document can be ammended to include that information. Thus helping everyone, rather than only folks why may find your post on stackoverflow. The repo for this project is https://github.com/dhermes/bezier, so please do file a docs update request there even though you personally have an answer to your question already.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Agreed. I simply was not sure was it a package documentation issue. (For example, post-processing of `matplotlib` results in order to get desired opacity output might be a "common" knowledge or done with a simple command I was not aware of.)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Issue submitted: https://github.com/dhermes/bezier/issues/290 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library is not well-documented, and apart from the axis and the general color for both line and area, there seems to be nothing that you can pass on to the plot. But we can retrieve the plotted objects (in this case, the plotted Bezier curve consists of a Line2D and a PathPatch object) and modify them:

```
import bezier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

nodes0 = numpy.asfortranarray([[0.0, 1.0, 2.0], [0.0, -1.0, 0.0]])
edge0 = bezier.Curve(nodes0, degree=2)

nodes1 = numpy.asfortranarray([[2.0, 2.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
edge1 = bezier.Curve(nodes1, degree=1)

nodes2 = numpy.asfortranarray([[2.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 2.0, 1.0]])
edge2 = bezier.Curve(nodes2, degree=2)

nodes3 = numpy.asfortranarray([[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0]])
edge3 = bezier.Curve(nodes3, degree=1)

curved_poly = bezier.CurvedPolygon(edge0, edge1, edge2, edge3)


curved_poly.plot(pts_per_edge=12, color="green", ax=ax1) 

for item in ax1.get_children():
    if isinstance(item, Line2D):
        item.set_color("red")
        item.set_alpha(0.7)
    if isinstance(item, PathPatch):
        item.set_alpha(0.1)
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response -- very instructive! (I was experimenting -- before I posted my question -- trying to modify / massage the plot objects into opacity I want, but did not succeed.)

Comment: Do you mean you did not exceed with this approach? What are the problems?

Comment: No problems with your approach. I was trying to say I attempted to find solutions in the same vein without success.

Comment: Well, the problem is that you have to retrieve immediately the Line2D and PathPatch objects representing the Bezier curve because if you plot multiple objects, you wouldn't know which of them belongs to your curves. I think they are prepended, i.e., Line2D[0] and PathPatch[0] would be the last curve generated. Unless, of course, you want to give all Bezier curves the same attributes; then, this approach is directly applicable. Too bad, that they don't allow passing parameters to matplotlib, return the objects, or document their source code.

Comment: Thanks again! (I put your user name in the "Acknowledgments" section in this package [`RandomMandala`](https://pypi.org/project/RandomMandala/).)

Comment: Mr. T feels honored. If this is for a project, it might be worth writing a function that not only sets the attributes but also returns the Line2D/Path objects for later manipulations. Something the original Beziers library should do.

Comment: "If this is for a project, it might be worth writing a function that [...]" -- Seems like a good idea, but is of low priority for me. :)